# How can be consumerkey passed to the HTTP headers?

Tags: asp.net, http-headers

How can be consumerkey passed to the HTTP headers?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Response.AddHeader method for it.

[Here is description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.addheader%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).